# I have an overnight layover in Frankfurt. Can I leave the airport?

Tags: germany, layovers

I am a U.S. citizen and have a overnight layover in Frankfurt Airport. Can I leave the airport for a night out in the city and then come back? Do I need a specific travel visa?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You will find the official resource in *[Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)*, but the short answer is no: a U.S. citizen does not need a visa to enter the Schengen area for a night.

Comment: Wasn't this airport closed during the night anyway so that everyone *has* to leave the airport? As a US citizen, you shouldn't face problems, at least if you are not coming close to staying 90 days in the Schengen area in a 180 day window.

Answer (score 4):

No problem. US citizens with a valid passport can stay for up to 90 days Visa free

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Germany.html

Frankfurt Airport has excellent public transportation connection to the city (S-Bahn). I'd recommend being back at the airport two hours or so before an international departure. It's a huge airport and lines can be long busy at times.